# apache throws 500 error on php error

Tags: php, apache-http-server, http-status-code-500

Hey guys, I just installed apache2 with curl and php5.  I haven't touched the config files, and every time my php throws an error (function doesn't exists, variable not set, etc), instead of display an error message (like my code says to) the server throws a 500 internal server error.  While this isn't inaccurate, I would like a little more information for the dev site, and a prettier error screen for the production site.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks,
Max

Comment: Check the Apache logs. They should say something `C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\error.log` or `C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\access.log`

Comment: That is how I figured out it was php errors causing the 500 headers.  Though they just give the error information, and that's it.

Comment: Have you tried running the PHP directly without Apache in the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `display_errors = off` in your *php.ini* file. You need to set it to `on`.